# Date formatting in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form where I input 3 fields (`firstname`, `lastname`, `date`), my problem is in the date formatting.

Here is an example. I input the `firstname`, `lastname` and the `date`.

[Preview of the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLtTx.png)

The `date` is well formatted => `01-02-1980` in the form.

However in my PhpMyAdmin, I have that => 318211200 it's the `date` :`S`

[Table in phpMyAdmin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wTu8J.png)

In my overview (panel), I also have `318211200` but not `01-02-1980`

[Overview panel](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC4hb.png)

In my **AdminController** I have that:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Student;

class AdminController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      $students = Student::oldest()->paginate(5);
      return view('admin.index', compact('students'))
             ->with('i', (request()->input('page',1)-1)*5);
    }

    public function store(Request $request)
    {

      $request->validate([
              'firstname' => 'required',
              'lastname' => 'required',
              'date' => 'required'
      ]);
      Student::create($request->all());
      return redirect()->route('admin.index')
                  ->with('success', 'save');
    }

}
```

And for my **index.blade**

```
<thead>
                <tr>
                  <th>Firstname</th>
                  <th>Lastname</th>
                  <th>Date</th>
                </tr>
                </thead>
                @foreach($students as $student)
                @php
                  $date=date('d-m-Y', $student['date']);
                @endphp
                <tr>
                   <td> {{$student->firstname}}</td>
                   <td> {{$student->lastname}} </td>
                   <td> {{$student->date}} </td>
```

Do you have an idea please? 
I thank you in advance

Comment: What is it exactly the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be it is because you used the 'time' column type. Try to define the column as 'date'. In your migration file you should write sth like

```
$table->date('date');
```

Answer (score 0):

The date column on the database table must be a `datatime` data type. So do any one of these two options:

**Option 1:**
In your migration file, change the code for the date column to

```
$table->dateTime('date');
```

Then run the artisan command to rollback and update your database

```
php artisan migrate:refresh
```

Then try submitting data from the form.

**Option 2:**

Manually change the data type of the `date` field on the table from phpMyAdmin.

You might have to truncate the database table, before submitting data from the form.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you might have the wrong datatype for your `date` column. Consider using a `datetime`.

If you wish you may alter the column on your table by:

```
ALTER TABLE students MODIFY date datetime;
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you havent posted your migration, Im going to have to guess that you havent defined your date column in database is not defined to have dates as input. So, i recommend you to update your migration for this particular table with following code and **refresh your migration**.

`$table->date('date');`

Now, you have a date enabled column to enter proper values. After this, I recommend you to use carbon to have date format and other amazing stuff managed by **Carbon**
If you are new to laravel, [check this video](https://laracasts.com/series/laravel-5-fundamentals/episodes/11) out which will give you a basic understanding, its little old but you will get the idea.

After you have done this, [check this page](https://scotch.io/tutorials/easier-datetime-in-laravel-and-php-with-carbon) where it has all possible out of the box options that you may use to manipulate dates. Any issue, let me know

happy coding!